# Can not find format drive C option when installing windows

Tags: installation, windows-installation

When inserting my Windows installing CD to my new Pc  to install windows, I did not see the "format C " option which I used to see on my old Pc.

Why that happened ? and how to fix it  ? 
Thank you

Comment: Which version of Windows you have? If it's a new PC with possibly a completely blank drive (raw) you shall see 'Unpartitioned Space' rather than any Drive Letters, on a screen where it asks you 'Where to install windows'..

Comment: @pat2015 , thanks for reply , it was  windows 7 which my Pc came with, when trying to install Xp pack 3 I could not see the format option. The drive also came  partitioned to 2 drives. So I did not saw "unpartioned space".      To install Xp   I had to creat another partion and install xp on it and to delete the partion where windows 7 installed.  I tried latter to repartion my HD but that did not fix the problem and get me a HD with 3 partions and unallocated space

Comment: I tried to install XP through an installation CD. and I also tried  to install windows 7 through a CD but also I cant find the format option.